# Разные git name и email настройки для разных проектов

Tags: git

```
$ git config --global user.name "firstname lastname"
$ git config --global user.email yourname@example.com
```

Вот таким образом мы создаем глобальные настройки для гита.
И после `git commit` вводя `git log` мы будем видеть свое имя и имейл в истории проекта.

Но, к примеру, если у вас ноутбук используется для хом проджектов и для работы.

И для хом проджектов вы хотите, чтобы логин был `coolvasya` с имейлом `coolvasya@myblog.com` а для рабочих проектов, чтобы было `vasya ivanov` с имейлом `vasya.ivanov@topcompany.com`

Насколько я знаю, это можно прописать в директории проекта `.git`, только где и в каком файле и как не могу понять и нагуглить.

Answer (score 5):

пишете в проекте 
git config  user.name "firstname lastname" ...
просто без --global

если указана опция --global, то эти настройки достаточно сделать только один раз, поскольку в этом случае Git будет использовать эти данные для всего, что вы делаете в этой системе. Если для каких-то отдельных проектов вы хотите указать другое имя или электронную почту, можно выполнить эту же команду без параметра --global в каталоге с нужным проектом.

Comment: Для сомневающихся можно `--global` заменить на `--local`

Answer (score 1):

У файла конфигурации говорящее название `config`:

```
.git\config
```